# Is isotopy type of brownian loops deterministic?

Tags: brownian-motion, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $B_1, B_2$ be two independants Brownian loops on $R^3$.

Does it almost surely exists a continuous isomorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto itself such that $\phi(Im(B_1))=Im(B_2)$? Can we chose $\phi$ homotopic to identity?

(just remark that this seems trivially true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>3$, since then the map $t\mapsto B_t$ is bijective, extends to a small tubular neighborhood, and then to the full $\mathbb{R}^3$ since there is "no knot" on dimension $4$. Thus every brownian loop is homotopic to a simple circle, thus they are homotopic between them.
As opposed to this, in dimension $3$, a Brownian loop knots and intersects itself a lot.)

Comment: What's a Brownian loop in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: It is a brownian bridge with initial point equal to final point. Fix a time horizon $T$ and an initial point $x$. A brownian loop in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is, roughly speaking, a brownian motion starting from $x$ and conditionned to come back to $x$ at time $T$. Both of the three components are independant $1D$ Brownian bridges.